# tar: extract myfile.tar.gz archive to a directory named myfile

Tags: bash, archiving, tar

Can it be done with tar?
Do I have to write a bash script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tar -xzf foo.tar.gz -C bar/
```

This extracts a gzipped foo.tar.gz after changing directory to bar

Answer (score 2):

From tar 1.28 you can use `--one-top-level` option.

```
tar zxvf archive_name.tar.gz --one-top-level
```

This extracts `archive_name.tar.gz` to a directory named `archive_name`.

Or make a bash function in your .bashrc file, sou you can use it anywhere.
I called it tar2dir.

```
tar2dir() {
        mkdir $(basename $1 .tar.gz)
        tar xf $1 -C $(basename $1 .tar.gz)
}
```